# java connecting to webservice receive SunCertPathBuilderException

Tags: java

I am using a webservice that was working fine till today. As of today morning, I have been getting the following error. Not everybody is having this issue. Can somebody point to why this might suddenly happen. Do I need to get the latest version of java?

```
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to this. It seems to fix the same problem that you are facing.

https://blogs.oracle.com/gc/entry/unable_to_find_valid_certification

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get the cert from the website and install it into cacert, but when i try to run the program again, its asking me for the certificate again, even though its already installed.

Comment: Maybe you need to register that certificate into "cacerts" keystore. Check it out the last paragraph:

"To use it in your program, either configure JSSE to use it as its trust store or copy it into your $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security directory. If you want all Java applications to recognize the certificate as trusted and not just JSSE, you could also overwrite the cacerts file in that directory."